# PHP append to file on other server

Tags: php, append

I want to append data to a file that is on another server.
Was wondering if the code below will work:

```
$fp = fopen('http://192.168.2.34:1234/Planet/data.txt', 'a+');

fwrite($fp, $successString);
fwrite($fp, '/n');
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: what stops you from giving a try?

Comment: I did and it didn't work of course. It doesn't make sense when I think about it. What about posting vars data to the other server? That should work right? I'll give it a try and post what happens....

Answer (score 2):

I'll spoil it: no, it won't work. There needs to be a service that handles the HTTP connection on the other end, which may then itself write something to a file. You cannot access files on remote hard disks directly over HTTP. And thank god for it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options for writing a file to a remote sever using something like the above would be using `FTP access` with `allow_url_fopen` enabled in php.ini and like follows:

```
<?php
$file = fopen ("ftp://ftp.example.com/incoming/outputfile", "w");
if (!$file) {
    echo "<p>Unable to open remote file for writing.\n";
    exit;
}
/* Write the data here. */
fwrite ($file, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n");
fclose ($file);
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php

However the source also states:

> Note: You might get the idea from the example above that you can use this technique to write to a remote log file. Unfortunately that would not work because the fopen() call will fail if the remote file already exists. To do distributed logging like that, you should take a look at syslog().

Therefore you cannot append using the above method, if you are sending a system log message to a remote server use `syslog()` as this is designing for that purpose.

Of the top of my head, you could potentially use something like `SSH` if on a linux machine or cygwin if on a Windows machine on either side to append to a file using PHP. But you would need `SSH access to the remote machine`.

```
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist"); // log in at server1.example.com on port 22 if(!($con
= ssh2_connect("server1.example.com", 22))){
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n"; } else {
    // try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "root", "secretpassword")) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
    } else {
        // allright, we're in!
        echo "okay: logged in...\n";

        // execute a command
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "EXECUTE SSH COMMAND HERE TO APPEND" ))) {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
        } else {
            // collect returning data from command
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $data = "";
            while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                $data .= $buf;
            }
            fclose($stream);
        }
    } }
```

Source: http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/

p.s. The reason you cannot do what you are asking in your example above in that scenario, is that if it were possible, **ANYONE** would be able to write to files on any server. As you can imagine this would be a `great security risk!`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this; you'd probably get an error message like this:

> PHP Warning:  fopen(http://example.com/data.txt): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections